# Which STL data structures with an incomplete type stored can be used as a class member?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, standards, forward-declaration

As far as I know, since C++17 some STL data structures may "exist" with an incomplete type as the template parameter which describes the type stored. For example, I may use `std::unique_ptr<Incomplete>` (I'm not sure if it's a data structure though) or `std::vector<Incomplete>` as class members if all properties of the class (which need `Incomplete`'s definition) are implemented in a separate .cpp file:

```
class Incomplete;
using Complete = int;
class Foo {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Incomplete> u_p;
  std::vector<Incomplete> v;
  std::deque<Incomplete> d;
  std::list<Incomplete> l;
  std::set<Incomplete> s;
  std::unordered_map<Complete, Complete> u_m_cc;
  std::unordered_map<Complete, Incomplete> u_m_ci;
  std::unordered_map<Incomplete, Complete> u_m_ic;
  std::unordered_map<Incomplete, Incomplete> u_m_ii;
public:
  // implemented in a separate .cpp which has Incomplete defined:
  Foo();
  Foo(Foo&&);
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&);
  Foo(Foo const&);
  Foo& operator=(Foo const&);
  ~Foo();
};
```

So, which of the data members listed above are valid for such usage? What about other data structures, smart pointers etc.?

Comment: Does it compile or not? If not, which members result in diagnostic message?

Comment: @eerorika `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` are fine, `std::unordered_map` refused to work on my MSVC: "std::pair uses incomplete struct". Even if it does compile something, it's not guaranteed to be in the standard, that's the trouble I see in such testing.

Comment: STL containers which allocate on the heap will work with incomplete types. Those allocated on stack won't and will require the appropriate headers included. `std::pair` is a POD, so any containers with `std::pair` as a member would not work with incomplete types. One interesting exception to this is `union` where allocation is on the stack but just the first member of the union list needs to be a complete type. The others can be incomplete. If i recall, `std::optional` exploits this property.

Comment: @cplusplusrat is it stated in the C++17 (or former) standard? Does it mean I can't use std::unordered_map with incomplete types stored? If it does, is there an alternative?

Comment: @walnut: How could a trivial type (automatically) own heap resources?

Comment: @DavisHerring I was referring to the `std::pair` itself, not its members. Like any other type the `std::pair` itself can be on the stack or heap. I mentioned that because the first few sentences in the comment I replied to made it sound to me as if `std::pair` being trivial somehow prevented `std::unordered_map` from accepting incomplete types, which as far as I can tell is not the case.

Comment: If anyone is interested: to proceed with just a forward-declaration, use boost containers with heap allocation (and appropriate allocators, obviously; the default one is OK): it's allowed explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming none of the classes members are used explicitly or implicitly until the type is complete:

The template argument can always be incomplete for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` since C++11, see [[unique.ptr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/unique.ptr#5) and [[util.smartptr.shared]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/util.smartptr.shared#2) respectively.

Support of incomplete types in containers was added with [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html) to C++17, but only for

```
std::vector
std::list
std::forward_list
```

and only if the allocator used fulfills the *allocator completeness requirements*, namely that, even if the value type itself is not complete, the allocator type `X` itself is a complete type and so are all members of `std::allocator_traits<X>`, except `::value_type`. The default allocator `std::allocator` fulfills these requirements.

None of the other containers can be used with incomplete types. According to the proposal linked above the scope was limited to these three containers "*as a first step*" because the major implementations already had support for it.

Answer (score 2):

> since C++17 some STL data structures may "exist" with an incomplete type as the template parameter which describes the type stored.

This is incorrect.

Since C++17, some STL types may **be declared** with an incomplete type as the template parameter.

By the time the types are **instantiated**, the types must be complete.

For example: (untested code)

```
struct T; // incomplete
using TV = std::vector<T>; // declared a type using incomplete type T; fine.

TV tv0; // attempt to declare a variable of type TV; fails to compile.

struct T { int v; }; // T is now complete
TV tv1; // compiles
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I still don't understand which of the usages I described are valid, if any. Can you help with this part?

Comment: In OP's example none of the containers members are instantiated until the type is complete. Instantiating the `std::vector` itself (but not its members) with incomplete type is explicitly allowed in C++17. I don't see how your explanation answers the question.

Comment: The types `list`, `forward_list` and `vector` are explicitly called out in C++17